How does "Useless cat. ... or 'cmd file | ..' instead." should be applied?
I have the following line:
isUbuntu=$(cat /etc/os-release | grep '^ID=ubuntu$' | wc -l)

It works fine
Now, through VSC and mostly with the ShellCheck extension is indicated two warnings messages as follows by parts:
For the latter:
Consider using 'grep -c' instead of 'grep|wc -l'.
shellcheck(SC2126)

Therefore the command is changed to:
isUbuntu=$(cat /etc/os-release | grep -c '^ID=ubuntu$')

and it works fine yet
For the former:
Useless cat. Consider 'cmd < file | ..' or 'cmd file | ..' instead.
shellcheck(SC2002)

Where it offers two suggestions to apply:

One: with cmd < file | ..

Then if cmd is the cat command then the command is changed to:
isUbuntu=$(cat < /etc/os-release | grep -c '^ID=ubuntu$')

and it works fine yet. Therefore until this point the two original messages are fixed.
Now the reason of this post is about the second suggestion:

Two: with cmd file | ..

Is it not the same cat /etc/os-release command applied from the beginning? Did I miss something? Therefore:
Question

How to apply correctly the cmd file | ..  suggestion?

Pls provide an example

that cmd < file | .. suggestion looks like it's assuming a longer pipeline, i.e. cat file | cmd | .. would be better turned into cmd < file | ... But in your case, the part corresponding to | .. is nothing, since you only have one command there in addition to the cat.

In this case cmd is referring to grep itself.  grep can read from a file so your full command could (and arguably should) be simply this:
grep -c '^ID=ubuntu$' /etc/os-release

The reason it suggests < file is because some commands cannot accept a file as an argument so you can use < file to send it to stdin instead of cat file.
Additionally even some commands that can accept the file as a command line argument will differ in behavior when it is supplied via stdin so you might prefer one or another.
tr is an example of the latter.  You wouldn't be able to do:
tr '-' '+' file
but you could do:
tr '-' '+' <file
See: UUOC

Of course as Stéphane pointed out, /etc/os-release is intended to be used in shell scripting so you could just:
. /etc/os-release
if [[ $ID == ubuntu ]]; then
  ...
fi

or
. /etc/os-release

case $ID in
    ubuntu) ubuntu_thing;;
    debian) debian_thing;;
    *)  unknown_thing;;
esac


Or isUbuntu=$(grep -xc ID=ubuntu /etc/os-release) here, though one doesn't need to get a count here. Could be if grep -xq ID=ubuntu /etc/os-release; then whatever you want to do if it is a Ubuntu system; fi. But /etc/os-release is intended to be shell code, so one can do . /etc/os-release || exit; case $ID in (ubuntu) ...; esac.

Even with grep using <file grep pattern instead of grep pattern file has advantages. See also When should I use input redirection?

Thank You for the answer - about: In this case cmd is referring to grep itself message - it was confuse because the warning message appears for the /etc/os-release  part where even it is marked with an underlined blue line so I assumed it is for the cat command.

Thus it seems there are 3 ways, my first approach in the OP, the current approach in this answer (that represents the second suggestion applied) and finally the grep command with input direction that really  represents the first suggestion indicated. Of course my approach was bad interpreted but shellcheck is not complaining anymore.

@ManuelJordan In most cases there isn't anything wrong with useless use of cat, it's just something to be aware of.

Thanks for the feedback

There's always a fourth ;-)  grep -q '^ID=ubuntu$' /etc/os-release and check the exit status.  [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && isUbuntu=1
